# How to do Arithmetic operations between two nodes of Firebase Realtime Database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am having two tables `Customers` and `Transaction` nodes. Transaction node is related to data of `Customer` node by Vehicle Number a data in Customer node. I want to subtract the amount paid from the Customer node Due Amount

Customer Table:-

```
"Customers": {
    "-NFFTcWFGLXi063jCTcT": {
      "branch": "Rajeev Nagar",
      "currentDownPayment": "80000",
      "currentdueAmount": "20000.0",
      "customerAadharNumber": "123456",
      "customerAddress": "ANYWHERE",
      "customerName": "VIKASH",
      "customerPhoneNumber": "7481900892",
      "customerTenure": "12",
      "dateOfdelevry": "28/10/2022",
      "downPayment": "100000",
      "duePayment": "100000.0",
      "emiPerMonth": "8333",
      "emiStartDate": "26/10/2022",
      "granterName": "RATHI",
      "granterPhoneNumber": "7481900896",
      "localitymodal": "NEAR ME",
      "motorNumber": "QWERT",
      "outStandingAmount": "120000.0",
      "vehicleAmount": "200000",
      "vehicleBodyType": "Steel",
      "vehicleColour": "Gray",
      "vehicleNumber": "1234567890QWERTYU"
    },
```

Transection table:-

```
Transaction": {
    "1234567890QWERTYU": {
      "-NFFZLr7-9sTrZ1OlbjF": {
        "dateOfPayment": "27/10/2022",
        "discountGiven": "00",
        "discountRemarks": "8000",
        "lateFine": "no discount ",
        "paymentReceived": "500"
      }
```

The key of the Transaction Table is the same as the Customer Table Vehicle Number see the last data of the Customer Table

databasePaymentUpdate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customers");

```
    databasePaymentUpdate.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String VehicleNumber = ds.child("vehicleNumber").getValue(String.class);
                    String vehNo = PaymentUpdateVehicleNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (VehicleNumber.equals(vehNo)) {

                        Toast.makeText(PaymentUpdate.this, "Welcome to Jyoti Motors", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

Comment: Can you share any code that you've tried so far? The only way is to read both the nodes and add the values manually. Also Firestore is a different database so I removed that tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok tell me one thing how should i read the value of respective customer and perform operations manually

Comment: databasePaymentUpdate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customers");        databasePaymentUpdate.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String VehicleNumber = ds.child("vehicleNumber").getValue(String.class);
                        String vehNo = PaymentUpdateVehicleNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                        if (VehicleNumber.equals(vehNo)){ }

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you have to use nested listener, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference customersRef = db.child("Customers");
customersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> customersTask) {
        if (customersTask.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot customerSnapshot : customersTask.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String vehicleNumber = customerSnapshot.child("vehicleNumber").getValue(String.class);
                DatabaseReference vehicleNumberRef = db.child("Transaction").child(vehicleNumber);
                vehicleNumberRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> vehicleNumberTask) {
                        if (vehicleNumberTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            long sum = 0;
                            for (DataSnapshot paymentSnapshot : vehicleNumberTask.getResult().getChildren()) {
                                String paymentReceived = paymentSnapshot.child("paymentReceived").getValue(String.class);
                                sum += Integer.valueOf(paymentReceived)
                            }
                            Log.d("TAG", "sum: " + sum);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

And the result in the logcat will be:

```
sum: 500
```

Please also note, that is recommended to store the prices as numbers and **not** as strings, case in which the above addition should look like this:

```
long paymentReceived = paymentSnapshot.child("paymentReceived").getValue(Long.class);
sum += paymentReceived;
```

Comment: Hey Vivek. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: sure sir i will use it today inform you thankyou for your response

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works. Looking forward to seeing your response.